# Which one should I use while designing a REST API in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, design-patterns

While designing a REST API using Spring Boot which you should prefer and why?

1. Wrapping the result into a `ResponseEntity<T>` and use the appropriate response code like below:

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<List<EmployeeDTO>> allEmployee() {

   return new ResponseEntity<>(employeeService.allEmployees(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

2. Directly return the result without changing anything, like below:

```
@GetMapping
 public List<EmployeeDTO> allEmployeeNew() {

    return employeeService.allEmployees();
 }
```

Share your best practice thoughts :)

Answer (score 2):

`ResponseEntity` will give you more flexibility to manipulate the response codes as per your design, for example you can also respond with a 201 status or 404 status based on what is the agreed API contract. You can also add custom response headers if you use this approach.

On the other side, directly returning the object as API response uses Spring's inbuilt response handler and will return 200 status code in case the API completed successfully and error statuses in case the API encountered any error scenarios.

If you feel you need to customize the HTTP status codes / custom response headers as per your design then it is good to return `ResponseEntity`, completely depends on your usecase.

There will be no difference in response body irrespective of whichever approach you take.

Hope it helps!!

Good luck!